# How expose multiple services on the same port in kubernetes using OpenStack

Tags: kubernetes, openstack, kubernetes-ingress

I have a Kubernetes cluster on a private cloud based on the OpenStack. My service is required to be exposed on a specific port. I am able to do this using NodePort. However, if I try to create another service similar to the first one, I am not able to expose it since I have to use the same port and it is already occupied by the first one.

I've noticed that I can use LoadBalancer in public clouds for this, but I assume this is not possible in OpenStack? 
I also tried to use Ingress Controller of Kubernetes but it did not worked. However, I am not sure if I went through a correct way to do it.
Is there any other way else than LoadBalancer or Ingress to do this? (My first assumption was that if I dedicate my pods to specific nodes, then I should be able to expose each of services on the same port on different nodes, but this approach also did not worked.)

Please let me know if you have any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup the [OpenStack Cloud Provider](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-openstack/tree/master/examples/loadbalancers): basically, this *Deployment* will watch for *LoadBalancer Service* and will provide an `{internal,external}` IP address you can use to interact with your application, even at L4 and not only (sic) L7 like many *Ingress Controller* resources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've see the page before, but using those approaches, OpenStack was not assigning any external IP to my services (it was empty). Is there any reason for this?

Comment: you have to debug the OpenStack Cloud Provider deployment: please take a look to logs to gather more information to understand the root cause

Comment: Do you mean logs of my deployment? I could not find anything there! The externalIP says: "Pending"

Comment: Nope, the log of the OpenStack Cloud Provider

Comment: Ok, I read more carefully your answer and probably you're missing the setup of the cloud provider! Please follow this useful post and ensure your cluster is configured correctly: http://henriquetruta.github.io/openstack-cloud-provider/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only expose one port then the only answer to the best of my knowledge is an ingress-controller. The two most famous ones are Nginx and Traefik. I agree that setting up ingress-controller can be difficult and I had problems with them before but you have to solve them one by one.

Another thing you can do is you can build your own ingress controller. What I mean is to use a reverse proxy such as Nginx, configure it to reroute the traffic based on your topology then just expose this reverse proxy so all the traffic goes through this custom reverse proxy but this should be done just if you need something very customized.